# Select columns from a table based on two different where clauses / joins - if one column matches use that, if not then use another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a SQL query that will `SELECT` columns from table 2 based on equality between one of two columns in table 1.

I understand I can't JOIN on multiple columns. Conceptually I want it to JOIN on a common column, call it column 1, if column 1 exists (not NULL) in both tables, else JOIN on a different common column, call it column2.

Since a `JOIN` like this isn't legal, I came up with an alternative with multiple `COALESCE`'s but it is far too slow for my purposes (there will be a lot of rows in those tables):

The two `WHERE` clauses represent checking if the first column exists or not in both tables and then checking the second column.

My query will need to select *n* columns from table2. How it is currently I have to add *n* `COALESCE` statements, which is really inefficient.

Does anyone know a way of doing this query all at once, i.e. without coalescing multiple times? Or another way of making it performant?

Minimum reproducible example:

```
/* Definition query */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [foo] [bigint] NULL,
    [bar] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [qux] [bigint] NULL,
    [quux] [nvarchar](50) NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table2](
    [baz] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [qux] [bigint] NULL,
    [quux] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [corge] [bigint] NULL
);

/* Sample data */
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([foo], [bar], [qux], [quux]) VALUES (1, N'asd', 345, NULL);
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([foo], [bar], [qux], [quux]) VALUES (2, N'fas', NULL, N'abc');
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([foo], [bar], [qux], [quux]) VALUES (3, N'fasfdjka', 678, NULL);
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([foo], [bar], [qux], [quux]) VALUES (4, N'jggiy', NULL, N'def');
INSERT [dbo].[table2] ([baz], [qux], [quux], [corge]) VALUES (N'afsfsaf', 345, N'xyz', 764694659);
INSERT [dbo].[table2] ([baz], [qux], [quux], [corge]) VALUES (N'jjuiku', 8910, N'abc', 519285912);
INSERT [dbo].[table2] ([baz], [qux], [quux], [corge]) VALUES (N'gghsd', 678, N'vuw', 152512512);
INSERT [dbo].[table2] ([baz], [qux], [quux], [corge]) VALUES (N'oolas;p', 111213, N'def', 921839129);


/* Select query */
SELECT t1.foo, t1.bar  ,
    COALESCE(  
    (  
    SELECT top 1 t2.baz 
   FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE t2.qux = t1.qux   
    ),  
    (  
    SELECT top 1 t2.baz 
    FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE  t2.quux = t1.quux
    )  
    ) AS baz, 
    COALESCE(  
    (  
    SELECT top 1 t2.corge 
   FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE t2.qux = t1.qux   
    ),  
    (  
    SELECT top 1 t2.corge 
    FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE  t2.quux = t1.quux
    ) ) AS corge  
FROM  table1 as t1
```

Here is the result I am getting, which is the desired result. But when you operate on large tables it is far too slow, which makes it inviable.

[Coalesce result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDM4h.png)

I tried `INTERSECT` in place of `COALESCE` but it gives me this result with `NULL`'s in both columns I trying to select from table 2, which is not desired:

```
SELECT t1.foo, t1.bar  , 
    (SELECT top 1 t2.baz 
   FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE t2.qux = t1.qux
    INTERSECT  
    SELECT top 1 t2.baz 
    FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE  t2.quux = t1.quux)
    AS baz,
    (SELECT top 1 t2.corge 
   FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE t2.qux = t1.qux   
    INTERSECT
    SELECT top 1 t2.corge 
    FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE  t2.quux = t1.quux)
    AS corge
FROM  table1 as t1
```

[Intersect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2U6p.png)

I tried using `EXCEPT` instead of `COALESCE` and it gave me a different result, but not a desired one:

```
SELECT t1.foo, t1.bar  , 
    (SELECT top 1 t2.baz 
   FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE t2.qux = t1.qux
    EXCEPT  
    SELECT top 1 t2.baz 
    FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE  t2.quux = t1.quux)
    AS baz,
    (SELECT top 1 t2.corge 
   FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE t2.qux = t1.qux   
    EXCEPT
    SELECT top 1 t2.corge 
    FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE  t2.quux = t1.quux)
    AS corge
FROM  table1 as t1
```

[Except result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqLSB.png)

Thanks

Comment: Tag only the **single** rdbms you want your solution in!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: INTERSECT and EXCEPT comes to my mind to push this business logic as a set operation. However without a minimal reproducible example and a layout of said business logic I have no point to start from.

Comment: Also note that tables have _columns_, not fields. (A field is something different,.)

Comment: I have tagged just sql-server now, thanks :)

Comment: Do I need to include the table designs / sample data in the minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Well you can't make a reproducible example without data, so yes the sample data must be there, as well as your desired result and your attempt

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have added a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select 
    t1.foo
    ,t1.bar
    ,isnull(t2.baz, t3.baz) as baz 
    ,isnull(t2.corge, t3.corge) as corge
from #table1 t1
left outer join #table2 t2 on t1.qux = t2.qux
left outer join #table2 t3 on t1.quux = t3.quux
```

Returns:

| foo | bar | baz | corge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | asd | afsfsaf | 764694659 |
| 2 | fas | jjuiku | 519285912 |
| 3 | fasfdjka | gghsd | 152512512 |
| 4 | jggiy | oolas;p | 921839129 |

<>

Maybe give this a try:

```
select 
    t1.foo
    ,t1.bar
    ,t2.baz
    ,t2.corge
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on (t1.qux = t2.qux) 
                          or ((t1.qux is null) and (t1.quux = t2.quux))
```

Comment: This is so much faster thank you!!! 

Is there a way of only getting one row per match?
If you see in my query I had (in each subquery):

`SELECT top 1 t2.baz 
   FROM  table2 as t2  
    WHERE t2.qux = t1.qux`
 
So if there are multiple rows in table1 where that matching succeeds, I can just exclude all but one of those rows in the result?
 
I can do `DISTINCT` but I'm not sure if that achieves the exact same result in every possible instance.

Comment: If no one suggests a query that is faster anytime soon then I will mark yours as the solution.

Comment: It's still taking a bit of time but I'm guessing that's because there are two joins and maybe because it calls that `isnull` function multiple times. Either way it is a very big improvement on mine.

Comment: The second you gave is a decent amount faster than the first. Thanks.